# ASP.NET MVC project, from view to controller, NULL model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In an ASP.NET MVC project, I have a very complex model, part of the class is below (the class is BIG, I simplified it a lot, leaving only one property):

```
[Serializable]
public class SimulazioneModelComplete : SimulazioneModel
{
   public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

I put some properties on a form, like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreaEsito", "Simulazioni", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "CreaEsito", name = "CreaEsito", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
   Title:
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title) 
}
```

I put a simple submit button

```
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
```

And in the controller I have a method expecting a `SimulazioneModelComplete` model

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreaEsito(SimulazioneModelComplete model)
{
}
```

but when I click submit, the `model` parameter is always `NULL`.

I don't see some properties null, the whole model is null. I don't place the full code of class and form because they are BIG, and would be unreadable.

Someone can suggest reasons for a `NULL` model?

Comment: Why are you using  `[Serializable]`?

Comment: Please post the **rendered** HTML of your `<form>`. Also take a look at your browser's developer tools' Network activity tab. Finally, do you have any custom middleware?

Comment: How did you verify that `model` was `null`? Do you have a debugger breakpoint set in your controller action?

Answer (score 1):

I don't why to you need but since you are using enctype = "multipart/form-data" you need to add an attribute to your action parameter

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreaEsito([FromForm] SimulazioneModelComplete model)
{
}
```

Sometimes  in net core [FromBody] can work too.

And I don't know why do you need  id and name, maybe this would be better

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreaEsito", "Simulazioni", FormMethod.Post, 
new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

Answer (score -2):

I found the problem ... it was in the model.
The model included TWO properties with the same NAME, but different type.

Something in the binding process becomes mad and the whole model becomes null.

Comment: "The model included TWO properties with the same NAME, but different type." - this isn't possible, the compiler would complain. How did that happen?

Comment: I don't know HOW, I know I found two properties with the same name and different type.

Comment: Please share a screenshot of what you see.